# substr_compare() returns wrong value in php

Tags: php, substring

The third value is for the start position, so I put 2 and it should return 0.

But it returns "1", why?!

```
$txt1 = "Bearner";
$txt2 = "Learner";
$per = substr_compare($txt1, $txt2, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Start position' refers only to the start position in the **first** string, not both.

This is causing the strings being compared to be completely different. (In your case, you're comparing `'arner'` with `'Learner'`).

What you want to do is compare **both** strings from that point onward. To do that, you'll need to refer to substrings instead of the whole string when comparing.

```
$txt1 = "Bearner";
$txt2 = "Learner";
$per = substr_compare(substr($txt1, 2), substr($txt2, 2), 0);
```

If you run this code, you'll see that it returns 0 as expected.

Comment: So why not remove the first `substr()` call and keep `2` as the third parameter? https://3v4l.org/3iSLg

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes, that will have the same effect! I just personally prefer putting it this way, as I find it easier and clearer to understand

Answer (score 0):

Only the first parameter is cut at position `x`, the second parameter is kept intact. `substr_compare($txt1, $txt2, 2);` will compare 'arner' with 'Learner'.

```
$txt1 = "Bearner" ;
$txt2 = "arner" ;
$per = substr_compare($txt1, $txt2, 2); 
var_dump($per) ; // 0
```

If you want to compare two substrings, you need to cut them yourself :

```
$txt1 = "Bearner" ;
$txt2 = "Learner" ;
$per = strcmp( substr($txt1, 2), substr($txt2, 2) );
var_dump($per); // 0
```